# Blender and volume object using openvdb

Tags: volumetrics

I have openvdb library connected with Blender.

I am using Python API and my code is as follows:

```
array = np.array(images)
grid.copyFromArray(array)
```

it creates grid and fill with data.
The problem is that I dont know how to display data as volume object in Blender.
This piece of code creates an empty object, but how can I connect it with my grid?

```
bpy.ops.object.add(type='VOLUME', align='WORLD', location=(0,0,0), scale=(1,1,1))
```

Thanks for your advices.

Comment: I am thinking you should re-title this question as “how to make a volume using multiple images as slices.” Aside from that, I’m sorry I don’t have an answer for you.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, volumes can not be directly loaded from memory in Blender, see
https://devtalk.blender.org/t/getting-openvdb-grids-in-render-engine-2-83/12270
But you can go over your hard disk.

```py
import pyopenvdb as vdb

array = np.array(images)
grid.copyFromArray(array)
grid.name = 'density'

vdb.write(fname, grids=grid)

import bpy
bpy.ops.object.volume_import(filepath=fname, align='WORLD', location=(0, 0, 0), scale=(1, 1, 1))
```

Comment: The method `copyFromArray` returns `NotImplementedError: this module was built without NumPy support`. Any ideas?