# Is there any way of manually creating volume grid data?

Tags: python, volumetrics

I would like to know if there is a way of manually creating volume grids. Like the data we obtain from mantaflow simulations or import from external vdb files.

For example, is the creation of volume grids exposed in the API? What I would like to do in such case is to manually create a 3d matrix in python inside Blender and directly pass such matrix to a volume object to be rendered. Without having to create an openvdb file and inport it.

Comment: If you ask for 'best way' to do something, your question is likely to be closed because it is "asking for an opinion".  You can create meshes in python, that can then be rendered, including 3D grids of data, and many importers do precisely that.   Look into bmesh in the manuals or tutorials for one way to do this.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback on the question. I edited it to avoid this problem and make it more clear. I already maneged to create an openvdb file in python and import it into blender. But I would like to know if there is any way we can create the volume grids inside blender.

Comment: I think https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/238229/how-to-import-numerical-fluid-particle-data-to-blender may answer your question.

Comment: @james_t, thank you, but that's not quite it. In the question you posted, the objective is to create points in specific positions with specific velocities, but each point does not contain a scalar value which could be used in shading.  I would need for each point (x,y,z) to be related to a density, that could be shaded.

Comment: Could you use vertex colors for the density weights?

Comment: @MartyFouts Arent vertex colors only for surface? Or can them be defined for the volume? If they can be defined on the volume and I can edit them in the API it might be an option!

Comment: Ah, no, I don't think they'll work for the volume.  sorry for the false hope.

Answer (score 0):

you can write the grid data from python into an openvdb file on disk, and import it into blender. heres a thread that shows some samplecode:
[Blender and volume object using openvdb](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/214584/blender-and-volume-object-using-openvdb/238838#238838)
and he explains it step by step:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x0Zlb7vyaO4&ab_channel=SURFVisualisation